# Animate custom object variable

Tags: android, animation, interpolation

Let's say I have a custom object, like a Point class (I am not using the one from Android), and I need to slowly change its coordinates from a start value to an end value when the user double taps the screen. I have already all setup, but I can't get to "animate" this change. Do you know how I can do it?

I have already tried something like this, but got no change:
ObjectAnimator(point, "point.variable", final_value).start()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have set up the `ObjectAnimator` incorrectly.

Let's assume your `Point` class has an instance variable `xPosition` that is an Integer. In order to animate the `xPosition` with the `ObjectAnimator`, you would do this:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(new Point(), // Instance of your class
                     "xPosition", // Name of the property you want to animate
                     startValue, // The initial value of the property
                     ... intermediateValues ..., // Any other desired values
                     endValue) // The final value of the property
    .setDuration(duration) // Make sure to set a duration for the Animator
    .start(); // Make sure to start the animation.
```

The `ObjectAnimator` will attempt to update the property automatically after each frame, but in order for it to be successful, your class must have a proper setter method for the property in the format of `setYourProperty`. So in this particular example, your class must have a method called `setXPosition` (note the camel case).

If, for some reason, this is not working, then you fall back on a `ValueAnimator`. You set up the `ValueAnimator` a similar way.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startValue // Initial value of the property
                                         endValue) // Final value of the property
    .setDuration(duration); // Make sure to set a duration for the Animation.
```

The difference here is that you must manually update your property. To do so, we add an `AnimatorUpdateListener` to the animation whose `onAnimationUpdate` method will be called after each frame in the animation.

```
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // Manually call the xPosition's setter method.
        point.setXPosition(animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
```

And don't forget to start the animation.

```
anim.start();
```

For more details regarding `ValueAnimator` and `ObjectAnimator`, see Google's API Guide on Property Animation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator

Comment: Ok, I got it working. Thanks! Just another question: if I'm dealing with native variables, am I obliged to use ValueAnimator? Or can I use some kind of property to avoid implementing the UpdateListener?

Comment: If you're using ValueAnimator, you pretty much need to use the UpdateListener, otherwise you will have no way to actually relate the values the animator is producing to your variable. For most cases, ObjectAnimator should work fine as long as you're fine with supplying a proper setter method. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by native variables, but a variable that is declared locally cannot be used in a ValueAnimator since you can only reference a local variable from inside the UpdateListener if it is declared final, which would then prevent you from actually changing the value.

Comment: By native variable I mean those that are not defined by the user, in other words int, double, float, etc. Since they are not objects, I wouldn't know what to set as parameter in a ObjectAnimator. So would I have to use a ValueAnimator for them?

Comment: Those are more commonly referred to as primitive types. More than likely, any value you're animating is going to be an instance variable for an Object. In the example, we're animating an integer (primitive type), that is an instance variable of a Point (Object). The only way I can think of for a primitive type variable to not be associated with an Object is if it is defined locally, in which case, it cannot be animated. But if you somehow do end up in such a situation, then yes, you must use ValueAnimator. If it clarifies things, ObjectAnimator is just a subclass of ValueAnimator.

Comment: Ok, I think I got this part. And also I might be having some trouble expressing myself haha. What I want to know is how you animate a primitive variable that is not a parameter of any object? I mean, let's say I have an int and I want to animate it, what method do I use? ObjectAnimator(intVar, "value", 0, 1)? Something like this?

Comment: You would use ValueAnimator for that. You would make a ValueAnimator using ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 1) and then add an AnimationUpdateListener that sets intVar = animation.getAnimatedValues();. However, if the variable is a local variable (a.k.a. not part of an Object), then it cannot be referenced inside a nested inner class such as an anonymous AnimationUpdateListener unless it is declared as final, which then prevents you from changing the variable. I urge you to try it and see what I mean.

Comment: Ok, got it after all! Thanks!